# Something wrong with my modular JS code TypeError is not a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was trying to modularise the JS code but stuck at a point for quite a long time, I know the solution will be easy but just can't figure it out.
Here is the fiddle link:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9b6vmrgn/1/).

Adding code here as well.

```js
window.a = (function () {
  function abc() {
    alert("Hi");
  }
  return {
    abc: abc
  }
});


window.b = (function (aWindow) {
  function i() {
    aWindow.abc();
  }
  return {
    i: i
  }
})(window.a);
```

```html
<a href="#" class="abc" onClick="window.b.i()">Click Me</a>
```

**Error**

```
"<a class='gotoLine' href='#60:10'>60:10</a> Uncaught TypeError: aWindow.abc is not a function"
```

Comment: you're missing `()` for the first `IIFE` - i.e. otherwise it's NOT an IIFE and window.a is just that function as you've written it - either that or do `})(window.a())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed `()` on `window.a` definition so it's not executed.

```js
window.a = (function () {
  function abc() {
    alert("Hi");
  }
  return {
    abc: abc
  }
})();

window.b = (function (aWindow) {
  function i() {
    console.log(aWindow);
    window.a.abc();
  }
  return {
    i: i
  }
})(window.a);
```

```html
<a href="#" class="abc" onClick="window.b.i()">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: I knew it was something small but could not figure it out any reference to read this concept and clear it out in-depth once for all. Thanks for the help

Comment: This will help. https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-immediately-invoked-function-expression-iife/

Answer (score 2):

You need to call window.a to obtain an object from its prototype.

```js
window.b = (function(aWindow) {

  function i() {
    aWindow.abc();
  }

  return {
    i: i
  }

})(window.a()); //Call Window.a
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed `()` when calling `aWindow`. This snippet works well.

```js
window.a = (function () {
  function abc() {
    alert("Hi");
  }
  return {
    abc: abc
  }
});


window.b = (function (aWindow) {
  function i() {
    aWindow().abc();
  }
  return {
    i: i
  }
})(window.a);
```

```html
<a href="#" class="abc" onClick="window.b.i()">Click Me</a>
```